# Is it safe to mount same btrfs subvolume multiple times at same time?

Tags: linux-kernel, btrfs

I know that it is safe to mount multiple volumes from the same btrfs volume at the same time.  But what about the same subvolume?  The subvolume would be mounted from the same Linux kernel instance.  Though, one mount point may be inside of a LXC or Docker (or maybe Podman) container.

It seems to have no problems letting me do this, but I just wanted to make sure this is considered safe and if it is documented anywhere.